# How to use fetch function to delete data?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Here is my code the

```
var url = '/deltopics?_id=' + item._id;

fetch(url, {
    method: 'delete',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    that.refresh(0, author);
    ui.tips('delete success')
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

but is doesn't work?

Can anybody help me??

Comment: What is your definition  of "doesn't work"?

Comment: It seems obvious but you may also provide a hint which js framework and plugins you are using.